# How to use multiprocessing in the certain time

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am using multiprocessing to send 500k messages to queue, but it sent too quickly, and made the server down.

in case : for loop , it took **10 mins** to send 500k messages

in case : multiprocessing , it took **12 seconds** to send 500k messages

But, I need it send in 1 min slowly to avoid losing server .

Server to send message : 36 cores

Are there any solution to send 500k message in 1 min?

I am using python 3.11

Comment: you have created a DDOS case. How many requests can the server handle in a second (the database of the server), can't you send N (100) messages in 1 request

Comment: This is not clear. You "lost"  the server? What does that even mean? Are you sending messages from one server to another? One server to itself? Are you " losing"  the sender or the recipient?

Comment: Since your question was closed because you don't know how to phrase it properly, here is a code sandbox I made to illustrate what you need to do: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/focused-burnell-8l8nzr?file=%2Fmain.py%3A71%2C12

Answer (score 1):

With multiprocessing you can still decide the pool size. The for-loop sends 50K/minute, you need 500K/min, so use 10 processes.